# Getting a matrix of capacitance data from a touchpad

Tags: synaptics-touchpad, hardware-acceleration

I would like to access the raw data from my touchpad before the data is processed into a single X,Y coordinate. Instead, I would like a grid of values as portrayed here:

[image]

(image from howstuffworks.com/iphone3.htm)

I don't think this is possible with my touchpad (info below). However, if anyone has had any luck accomplishing this with a different touchpad model, or even touchscreen on any other device, I would like to know the model and how. And if anyone disagrees and knows how to do this on my model, even better!

My laptop uses a Synaptics PS/2 touchpad with hardware ID ACPI\SYN070B.

Looking at a diagram on page 17 of the [Synaptics API manual for a PS/2 touchpad](http://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/511-000275-01_RevB.pdf), it seems the processing occurs within the touchpad, and only a single point is sent to the driver, so I don't think it is possible for my touchpad.

Comment: This is likely done at hardware or firmware level, all the operating system receives is the "cleaned up" touch coordinate.

Comment: I think so for the PS/2 Synaptics, but there must be some models that send this information for multitouch gestures and such, no?